# Why velocity and accelleration must be linearly independent?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology, curves

I am struggling to understand the definition of biregular curve.

**Definition**

> A curve $I \ni t \mapsto P(t) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is said to be biregular when the velocity and accelleration vectors are linearly independent, that is when their cross product is different from zero $$dP/dt \land d^2P/d^2t \neq 0$$

**Q.**

> I read that this is equivalent to the fact that $$d \underline{t}/ds \neq 0$$ and this is what I am having trouble understanding. Why is so?

Recall that $$s= \int_0^t \|dP/dt\| \, dt,$$ is the curvilinean coordinate, and $$\underline{t}(s)=dP/ds$$ so that $$dP/dt= dP/ds \  \dot{s}= \underline{t} \ \dot{s}$$ where $$\dot{s}=ds/dt.$$

Moreover $$d^2P/d^2t= d\underline{t}/ds \ \dot{s}^2 + \underline{t} \ \ddot{s}.$$ Hence we have

$$dP/dt \land d^2P/d^2t = \underline{t} \ \dot{s} \land (d\underline{t}/ds \ \dot{s}^2 + \underline{t} \ \ddot{s})$$$$ = \dot{s}^3(\underline{t}\land d\underline{t}/ds)+\ddot{s}(\underline{t}\land \underline{t})=\dot{s}^3(\underline{t}\land d\underline{t}/ds).$$

So, the curve is biregular $\iff$ $\dot{s}=\|dP/dt\|\neq 0$ and $\underline{t}\land d\underline{t}/ds \neq 0.$

How is this equivalent to the fact that $d \underline{t}/ds \neq 0$?

> Why is it not possible that $d\underline{t}/ds$ and $\underline{t}$ are both different from zero and yet linearly dependent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't bring myself to use little letters for these vectors when we already have the time parameter $t$.

Because $\|T(s)\| = 1$ for all $s$, it follows that $dT/ds$ is orthogonal to $T$, so they will always be linearly independent provided $dT/ds\ne 0$.

Comment: I am sorry I still don't get it. Why the fact that $T(s)$ has unit norm imply it must be orthogonal to $T$?

Comment: Differentiate the equation $T(s)\cdot T(s)=1$ with respect to $s$.

Comment: of course, I am not very sharp tonight. Thank you.

Comment: Sure. No problem. If you're heading into differential geometry type material, you might download my (free) text, linked in my profile.

Comment: I'll take a look at it. Thank you